# Database optimization for subscriptions and activation codes

Tags: postgresql, database-design, nestjs

I wonder about the structure of the database and how it should be designed optimally.

Problem:
An application for publishing books, books is added by the administrator. There is a Cooperator module, when publishing a book to the platform, you can add a Cooperator. Cooperator has activation codes. The activation code allows the user to access content that has been tagged with a given Cooperator. You can purchase a subscription, a subscription gives you the opportunity to access books without the specified Cooperator. I do not know how to solve it correctly from the database side, to make it as optimal as possible, in addition, if the user does not activate the Cooperator code, he should not see these books at all.

Actual Database:

```
Book Entity:
Date Created
Date Updated
Id
Name
Categories 
Cooperator 

Cooperator Entity
Date Created
Date Updated
Id
Name
CodeBatches (One to Many)

Code Batche Entity:
Date Created
Date Updated
Id
Name
Access In Months
Cooperator (Many to One)
CodesActivation (One to Many)

Code Activation Entity
Date Created
Date Updated
Id
Status
Activation Code(Unique)
```

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you looking for the DDL, e.g. `create table Book ( id integer...)` ?